# Javascript AJAX Login not behaving

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery, authentication

I am creating an ajax login and it used to work but for some reason now it redirects me to my php login processing page. The code is below and I am using jquery ajax to submit my ajax request. The weird thing is that it apparently isn't sending the variables because my page doesn't echo the word 'success'. Any help would be appreciated and also, would this be secure to use?

---

Javascript(jQuery);

```
$('.mainlogin').submit(function() {
    var username = $('#main_username').val();
    var password = $('#main_pword').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'log.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            user: username,
            pass: password
            },
        success: function(response) {
            if (response == 'success') {
                    window.location.reload();
            } else {
                $('.logerror').fadeIn(250);
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

PHP;

```
<?php 
require_once('.conf.php');
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
$pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
//$remem = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['remem']);
//$expire=time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE username = '$user'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
if (sha1($user.$pass) == $row['pword']) {
    //setcookie('temp', $row['username']);
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['login'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['uname'] = $row['username'];
    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
    echo "success";
} 
}
?>
```

---

Thanks so much!! I can't figure this out and have run multiple javascript checks, none of which gave me an error.

Comment: Use firebug's Net panel to inspect what's actually being sent to and from the server - are the user and pass vars actually being sent? If so, add an else to the sha1 if and echo out the sha1 result and compare against what's stored in the DB, etc etc, standard debugging. The code seems fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the login processing page the value of your form's action attribute?  If so it sounds like the form is being submitted instead of your AJAX being called.

Are you testing in a browser where you can see the response from your PHP script?  Chrome/WebKit have a network tab where you can view the response of XHR (Ajax) requests.

You could try:

```
$('.mainlogin').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
```

as your anonymous function definition to prevent the from from being submitted in the standard HTML fashion.

Comment: I am building my site in safari so I have checked the network tab and it loads the log.php. I can't tell if the JavaScript is being run or not. Also because I specify an action in my JavaScript, it shouldnt matter d I specify one in HTML.

Comment: It loads log.php via AJAX?  Set your network tab filter to just 'XHR' and see if your AJAX request is there.  If so, click that request and pull up the "response" tab to see what PHP is pushing out.  It could very well be an error or warning.

Comment: That didn't work, the e.preventDefault(); and it is sending the username and password to the php code.

Comment: You still haven't given any info on the AJAX response from PHP.  Please give us more info--at this point I'm just walking you through how to debug AJAX step by step.

Comment: Well lets see, it gave me the correct username and password in the network tab. That makes me believe it is the javascript with the error.

Comment: How so?  If the correct username and password were submitted to PHP, that would lead me to believe the error was in your PHP script.  Do me a favor.  Change this `$('.logerror').fadeIn(250);` to this `alert(response)`.  What did you get?

Comment: I can't get any thing. It just reloads the page and I tried changed the window.location.reload(); to alert(response); but it just still reloads.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7768/discussion-between-joseph-torraca-and-casey-kinsey)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing there's in error in the Javascript somewhere that's causing the Javascript not to finish, therefore sending the user to the PHP page.

Try checking the browser console for errors.

Answer (score 0):

Is your php connected to Database?